# How to edit users from a database in a table format

Tags: php, database, admin, dashboard

I'm currently working on a project that envolves me using a admin dashboard. As apart of this i need to be able to display all users in the database and then edit them.

I want to be able to open the modal to edit the users, but whenever i open the modal its displaying the first entries data. How can i change this to display the different data for each line and then edit said data.

This is my current Code

```
<?php
  include_once '../dashboard/dashHeader.php';

?>
    
    <section>
        <table class="table table-striped" style="border: 3px solid;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>UID</th>
                    <th>Full Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>Role</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                include_once('../../includes/dbh.inc.php');
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER by usersId";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
                
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    if ($row['type'] == 1) {
                        $role = "Admin";
                    } else {
                        $role = "User";
                    }

                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['usersId']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['usersName']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['usersEmail']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['usersUid']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$role."</td>";
                    echo '<td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm btn-rounded" data-mdb-toggle="modal" data-mdb-target="#exampleModal">
                            Edit
                            </button>

                            <!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editing: '.$row['usersUid'].'</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">...</div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-mdb-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>';
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?>


            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>

<?php
  include_once '../dashboard/dashFooter.php';
?>
```

Comment: Add you modals have the same id's `id="exampleModal"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what your JavaScript is doing, it's hard to debug

But first...

... you really need to fix the security of this page.  This is vulnerable to HTML injection.  You MUST escape all dynamic content (eg from your database), otherwise at best you will show mangled data, at worst you make it easy for a hacker to inject any code they like into your web page.  At a minimum you should be running htmlspecialchars().

Ex `echo "<td>".htmlspecialchars($row['usersName'])."</td>";`